# Trying to deploy an SQL DB on Azure pipelines PATH ISSUE

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to deploy a .NET project which has multiple projects in it as well as an sql database(ssdt) but I'm having a hard time finding out what path to use to get the .dacpac generated.

In dotnet build I have Arguments: --configuration Release

I also want to know if the copy task is properly placed, or should it be below dotnet publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more general wildcard to find your dacpac, unless you're generating more than one, this would work:

- *.dacpac

As a troubleshooting tip, if you have trouble finding files generated on your agents, you can add a small bash script to your pipeline to list all files & the primary working directory:

```
echo "-----------------"
echo "-- Primary Working Directory"
pwd
echo "-- All Directories & Files"
ls -LR
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, and do you perhaps know if I should do the copy task after dotnet publish or before that?

Comment: I typically add my post-build scripts after publish to ensure that all of my build artifacts are complete before changing them. In this scenario, you should be good with it before or after the publish.